# Inspec: checking for user and group

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

What's the difference between these two?

```
it { should be_owned_by 'cool_user' }
vs
its('owner') { should eq 'cool_user' }

it { should be_grouped_into 'cool_group' }
vs
its('group') { should eq 'cool_group' }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference, just two ways to write it. https://github.com/chef/train/blob/master/lib/train/extras/file_common.rb#L107 and similar for the other.

Answer (score 0):

Inspec supports both [styles](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/resources/file/) .

```
it { should be_owned_by 'cool_user' }
it { should be_grouped_into 'cool_group' }
```

Though this style looks more like [serverspec](http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html#file) way of writing it :)